# How to properly override init() for UITableViewController subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, viewcontroller

My `UITableViewController` subclass `MatchTableViewController` has the following properties:

```
class MatchTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // MARK: - Properties
    var matches = [Match]()
    var dataModel: DataModel
    var apiModel: APIModel
```

I want to initialize `dataModel` and `apiModel` by overriding initializers.

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    // Init the DataModel
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    guard let historyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "History",
                                                         in: managedContext)
        else {
            fatalError("Failed to load the History entry")
    }
    self.dataModel = DataModel(historyEntity: historyEntity,
                               managedContext: managedContext)

    // Init the APImodel
    self.apiModel = APIModel()
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Error here
}


override init(style: UITableView.Style) {
    // Init the DataModel
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    guard let historyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "History",
                                                         in: managedContext)
        else {
            fatalError("Failed to load the History entry")
    }
    self.dataModel = DataModel(historyEntity: historyEntity,
                               managedContext: managedContext)

    // Init the APImodel
    self.apiModel = APIModel()
    super.init(style: style)
    // Error here
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Xcode gives me error `'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer` right after two `super.init` calls. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that if inside `guard` value isn't assigned, `super.init(...)` isn't called and non-optional variables aren’t assigned as well. But you want to throw `fatalError` in `else {...}` so calling `super.init(...)` here wouldn’t make any sense.

So first call `super.init(...)` and then do other stuff

```
override init(...) {
    super.init(...)
    ... // do other stuff
}
```

then make sure that you assign all non-optional global variables before you call `super.init(...)`. If don't (like your case), make these variables optional

```
var variable: Type?
```

Comment: I put `super.init(...` to the first line, then Xcode gives me error `Property 'self.dataModel' not initialized at super.init call`...

Comment: Setting my properties to optional gets rid of the error. I am kinda confused tho. Does it mean I cannot have non-optional properties when I subclass `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @JayWong no, it means that every property of any class/struct has to have value or no value (`nil`) if you make it optional after initialization ended. If you don't assign non-optional property inside its initialization, then this property would have no value which isn't possible (because it's non-optional, right?) so compiler warn you...

Comment: I see what you mean. However, in my code above, my properties are non-optional and I do assign values to them in my initializers (after the `super.init(...` calls). In this case, the compiler stills warns me `Property 'self.dataModel' not initialized at super.init call`, and the only workaround seems to be setting properties to optional...

Comment: @JayWong check edited answer, its because of `guard` statement

Comment: @JayWong you have to assign non-optional properties before super.init is called

Answer (score 1):

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}
```

when override the init method required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITableViewCell'

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```